# Difference in performance between initializing data using Javascript vs using MySQL for data retrieval?

Tags: javascript, mysql, database, performance

I'm developing a nodejs web application that involves using nutrient data to make some calculations. I've taken a database offered from the [USDA](https://www.ars.usda.gov/northeast-area/beltsville-md-bhnrc/beltsville-human-nutrition-research-center/nutrient-data-laboratory/docs/sr28-download-files/) and successfully created a local version that I'm using for development.

With the amount of data and the number of queries I've had to make, I thought about making Javascript dictionaries that would store object data, initializing them as I start up the nodejs application. I'm unsure if this is a reasonable solution, and am worried about performance changes this might cause. From a development standpoint however, I could see this being a sizable benefit.

This leads me to ask:

How might initializing data using Javascript be different than retrieving the same data using a database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That dataset might be under 60MB when stored in a database.  That is relatively small these days.  However, loading it from the database, through the server, to the client *might* be too slow.

The other approach is to construct SQL queries and hit the database for just the data needed.  This *might* be faster.  Let's see a sample the queries you plan to run.

Since the data is constant, it *might* be worth constructing the JSON for the entire dataset and having it as part of the JS code.

But to do that, you probably *should* build the database and write the SQL queries to build the JSON.

That is, you *should* do both approaches anyway.  *Then* see what feels better.

I *could* look at the data and guess at what would be better, but it would depend on my coding style and experience (or lack of it).  That would not necessarily apply to *your* coding style and experience.

The good news is such a small dataset is probably not going to be a performance hit, regardless of how you implement it.

(The data seems to be highly normalized, and would need several tables.)

Comment: How might a JSON solution be slower than a SQL solution?

Comment: @JasonKirk - JS loves JSON.  But, if it needs to unpack 60MB of JSON for every query, that could be more work than fetching a few dozen rows from a database.  What are your queries like?

Comment: I'm currently using a query chain of select statements such as

SELECT * FROM food_des WHERE NDB_No =   ___ .

Now that I know a little more about SQL, my best bet might be to use stored procedures? Especially knowing that the json would have to be unpacked for every query.

Comment: @JasonKirk - You probably would not use JSON in database tables, though you _might_ use it for sending the result of the query to Javascript.  Suggest you use plain queries first.  Stored Procs are handy for encapsulating, but they can give you headaches until you get the hang of the odd syntax.